# Restrict number of decimals to be displayed from DB

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am fetching some values from my DB. The columns are of float type and are being displaed in DataList in the following manner.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
    <td style="width:200px;text-align:left"> Item1: <%#Eval("Item1") %>  |  Item2: <%#Eval("Item2") %></td>
    </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
```

I have to restrict the number of decimal values being displayed int he data list to 3. How can I do that here?

In the code-behind, the data is being fetched into the DataTable as follows.

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Retrieve", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString);
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             adp.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@s1", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = strategies;
             adp.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@s2", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
             adp.Fill(ds);
             DataList1.DataSource = ds;
             DataList1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"<%# Eval("Value", "{0:0.###}") %>"

Try above code.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so why not just use something like this instead of playing with the database?

```
Eval("Item1", {0:#0.000})
```

Could also use Math.Round around your Eval?

Comment: `<%#Eval("Item", {0:#0.000}) %>` has invalid expression terms as the IDE points out.

Comment: <%# Math.Round(Eval("Item1", 3)) %>  ?